# JSON_Normalize (nested json) to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have been trying via pandas to extract data from a txt file containing json utf-8 encoded data.

Direct link to data file - http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/psc-snapshot-2022-02-06_8of20.zip

Data's structure looks like the following examples:

```
{"company_number":"04732933","data":{"address":{"address_line_1":"Windsor Road","locality":"Torquay","postal_code":"TQ1 1ST","premises":"Windsor Villas","region":"Devon"},"country_of_residence":"England","date_of_birth":{"month":1,"year":1964},"etag":"5623f35e4bb5dc9cb37e134cb2ac0ca3151cd01f","kind":"individual-person-with-significant-control","links":{"self":"/company/04732933/persons-with-significant-control/individual/8X3LALP5gAh5dAYEOYimeiRiJMQ"},"name":"Ms Karen Mychals","name_elements":{"forename":"Karen","surname":"Mychals","title":"Ms"},"nationality":"British","natures_of_control":["ownership-of-shares-50-to-75-percent"],"notified_on":"2016-04-06"}}
{"company_number":"10118870","data":{"address":{"address_line_1":"Hilltop Road","address_line_2":"Bearpark","country":"England","locality":"Durham","postal_code":"DH7 7TL","premises":"54"},"ceased_on":"2019-04-15","country_of_residence":"England","date_of_birth":{"month":9,"year":1983},"etag":"5b3c984156794e5519851b7f1b22d1bbd2a5c5df","kind":"individual-person-with-significant-control","links":{"self":"/company/10118870/persons-with-significant-control/individual/hS6dYoZ234aXhmI6Q9y83QbAhSY"},"name":"Mr Patrick John Burns","name_elements":{"forename":"Patrick","middle_name":"John","surname":"Burns","title":"Mr"},"nationality":"British","natures_of_control":["ownership-of-shares-25-to-50-percent","voting-rights-25-to-50-percent"],"notified_on":"2017-04-06"}}
```

The simple`pd.read_json` did not work  initially (I would get ValueError: Trailing data errors)  until `lines=true` was used (using jupyternotebook for this).

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_json(r'E:\JSON_data\psc-snapshot-2022-02-06_8of20.txt', encoding='utf8', lines=True)
```

this is how the data structure is displayed via `df.head()` :

```
    company_number  data
0   06851805    {'address': {'address_line_1': 'Briar Road', '...
1   04732933    {'address': {'address_line_1': 'Windsor Road',...
2   10118870    {'address': {'address_line_1': 'Hilltop Road',...
3   10118870    {'address': {'address_line_1': 'Hilltop Road',...
4   09565353    {'address': {'address_line_1': 'Old Hertford R...
```

After looking through stackoverflow and several online tutorials I tried using `pd.json_normalize(df)` but keep getting a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'` error. I would like to ultimately export this json file into a csv file.

thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that problem by applying the `json_normalize` just to the data column.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json(r'E:\JSON_data\psc-snapshot-2022-02-06_8of20.txt', encoding='utf8', lines=True)

#json_normalize
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

#output to csv
df.to_csv("./OUTPUT_FILE_NAME")

print(df)

   company_number  ... name_elements.middle_name
0         4732933  ...                       NaN
1        10118870  ...                      John

[2 rows x 24 columns]
```